# Clarification on Automatic Checkpoints and IO Latency Thresholds in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, checkpoint

I have been reading the [SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/database-checkpoints-sql-server) and came across the following statement about automatic checkpoints:

> Issued automatically in the background to meet the upper time limit suggested by the recovery interval server configuration option. Automatic checkpoints run to completion. Automatic checkpoints are throttled based on the number of outstanding writes and whether the Database Engine detects an increase in write latency above 50 milliseconds.

I'm trying to understand what "Automatic checkpoints run to completion" means. I'm not a native English speaker and this sentence sounds very weird to me. Are there any checkpoints do not run to completion and only do half of their work?

Additionally, I recall a statement from Paul Randal where he mentioned that the checkpoint process will throttle outstanding IOs if the IO latency is greater than 20ms. During shutdown, this threshold increases to 100ms to expedite the process. However, the SQL Server documentation suggests a threshold of 50 milliseconds for throttling automatic checkpoints. Has there been a change in the threshold value, or am I misunderstanding the concept?

Any clarification on these points would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any checkpoints do not run to completion and only do half of their work?

"Automatic checkpoints run to completion" simply means that no, there are not automatic checkpoints that only do half of their work.

> Additionally, I recall a statement from Paul Randal

Much of what Paul writes about are "internals", which while not secret, are intentionally *not documented*.  There may well be some undocumented complexity beyond the 50ms throttle trigger that is publicly documented.

It's important to document the *existence* of a trigger that forces checkpoint to slow down when it might be interfering with important work.  But not necessary to document the fine details, which are subject to change.